# Fitting a multilevel hierarchical model in WinBUGS - involving multivariate distribution

Tags: model, hierarchical, winbugs

I'm trying to learn how to fit hierarchical models in WinBUGS. As an exercise, I’ve simulated some dose response data in R with 3 levels, which I then try to feed into WinBUGS.

Simulation setting:

- 3 levels: `CENTER`, `SUBJECT`, `RESIDUAL`
- 20 centers
- Each center has 20 subjects
- Each subject has received 9 dose levels (ignore the realistic aspect of this design)
- The 9 dose levels are: `1`, `2`, `5`, `10`, `25`, `50`, `100`, `200`, and `500`
- The log(response of subject `i` at dose `j`)  = `log(exp(l.E0) + exp(l.EMAX)*(Dose/( exp(l.ED50) + Dose))) + residvar`
- `l.E0` = 0.693 (fixed effect)
- `l.ED50` = `l.ED50.MEAN + RANDOM.SUBJECT.ED50` **(so a subject specific l.ED50 effect)**
- `l.EMAX` = `l.EMAX.MEAN + RANDOM.CENTER.EMAX + RANDOM.SUBJECT.EMAX` **(so both a center and subject specific l.EMAX effect)**
- `l.ED50.MEAN` = 3.22 (fixed effect)
- `l.EMAX.MEAN` = 5.706 (fixed effect)
- `RANDOM.CENTER.EMAX ~ N(0, 1.14)`
- `RANDOM.SUBJECT.ED50 + RANDOM.SUBJECT.EMAX ~ MVN([0,0], [0.1036, 0.156, 0.156, 0.325])` **(so bivariate normal distribution with 0.85 correlation and 0.1036 and 0.325 variance for `ED50` and `EMAX` respectively)**

In the following I give the WinBUGS code I tried and the data. The model is synthactically correct but after compiling the data I receive some error messages that I do not understand.

I was wondering if someone could tell me:

- how to correct my code
- or if my attempt for coding the multilevel multivariate distribution is wrong and if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Kr,
Roel

```
model {
  for (k in 1:nobs) {
    #model for observed data
    yobs.log.prop[k] ~ dnorm(yobs.log.prop.hat[k], tau)          
    # likelihood        
    yobs.log.prop.hat[k] <- log(exp(mu.l.E0) + exp(l.ID.EMAX[nsub.unique.from1[k]]) * (dose[k]/(dose[k] + exp(l.ID.ED50[nsub.unique.from1[k]]))))
    l.ID.EMAX[nsub.unique.from1[k]] <- mu.l.EMAX + u.EMAX.CENTER[ncenter[k]] + u.ID[nsub.unique.from1[k], 1]
    l.ID.ED50[nsub.unique.from1[k]] <- mu.l.ED50 + u.ID[nsub.unique.from1[k], 2]
  }
  for (j in 1:20) {
    #intercenter variability: level1
    u.EMAX.CENTER[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau.l.EMAX)
    u.EMAX.CENTER.pred[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau.l.EMAX)
  }
  for (i in 1:400) {
    #intersubject variability: level 2
    u.ID[i, 1:2] ~ dnorm(zero2[1:2], tau.u2[1:2, 1:2])
  }
  #Priors fixed effects
  mu.l.E0 ~ dunif(-2, 5)
  mu.l.EMAX ~ dunif(1, 10)
  mu.l.ED50 ~ dunif(-2, 5)
  tau <- 1/(sigma*sigma)
  sigma ~ dunif(0,1000)
  #Prior for CENTER effect
  tau.l.EMAX <- 1/(omega.l.EMAX * omega.l.EMAX)
  omega.l.EMAX ~ dunif(0, 100)
  #omega.l.EMAX ~ dnorm(0,0.01)I(0,)
  #Prior for ID effect
  for (m in 1:2) {
    zero2[m] <- 0
  }
  tau.u2[1:2, 1:2] ~ dwish(R[1:2,1:2],2) 
  sigma.u2[1:2, 1:2] <- inverse(tau.u2[1:2, 1:2])
  rho <- sigma.u2[1, 2]/sqrt(sigma.u2[1,1]*sigma.u2[2, 2])
  #omega.l.EMAX~dnorm(0,0.01)I(0,)
}
```

I wanted to include the data but received message that I used to many characters. Therefore I only show the beginning (with specification of the Wishart R matrix) and a subset of my data.

```
list(nobs=3600, R = structure(.Data = c(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1), .Dim = c(2, 2)),
     yobs.log.prop=c(4.29774919346511, ...), #... are the remaining 3599 responses
     dose=c(1,  ...), #... are the remaining 3599 dose values
     ncenter=c(1, ....), #... are the remaining 3599 center identifications
     nsub.unique.from1=c(1...)) #... are the remaining 3599 subject identifications
```

Comment: Perhaps initially try compiling the model with a smaller data set (e.g. `nobs=100`) and then build up (e.g. `nobs=1000`, `nobs=2000`) until you get your error message. It might be that the error comes from the format of the input data.

Comment: "I receive some error messages that I do not understand" ... what are they?